# Accord.net Codification can't handle non-strings

Tags: accord.net

I am trying to use the [Accord.net library](http://accord-framework.net) to build test method of several of the machine learning algorithms that library supports.

One of the issues I have run into is that when I am trying to codify my string data, the Codification class does not seem capable of dealing with any datatable columns that are not strings, despite the documentation saying otherwise.

```
Codification codebook = new Codification(fulldata, AllAttributeNames);
```

I call that line where fulldata is a datatable, and I have tried including columns of both Int32 type and Double type, and the Codification class has thrown an error saying it is unable to convert them to type String.

"System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.String'.'"

EDIT: It turns out this error is because the Codification system can only handle alternate data types if it is encoding the entire table. I suppose I can see the logic here, although I would prefer a better error, or that the method was a little smarter.

I now have another issue that has cropped up related to this.  After changing my code to this:

```
Codification codebook = new Codification(fulldata);
```

I then learning.Learn(inputs, outputs) my algorithm and want to use the newly trained algorithm.  So the next step would be to take a bunch of test data, make sure it matches the codebooks encoding, and send it through the algorithm.  Unfortunately, when I try and use the

```
int[][] testinput = codebook.Transform(testData, inputColumnNameArray);
```

It blows up claiming it could not find a mapping to transform.  It does this in reference to an Integer column that the codebook correctly did not map to new values.  So now it seems this Transform method is not capable of handling non-string columns, and I have not found an overload of it that can, even though the [documentation](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Statistics_Filters_Codification.htm) indicates it should be able to handle this.

Does anyone know how to get around this issue without manually building the entire int[][] testinput array one value at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was able to answer my own question eventually.

The Codification class has two methods of using it as near as I can tell.  The constructor that takes a list of column names, as well as the Transform methods both lack intelligence in dealing with non-string data types, perhaps these methods are going away in the future.

The constructor that just takes a datatable by itself, as well as the Apply method, are both capable of handling data types other than strings.  Once I switched to using these two methods my errors went away.

```
Codification codebook = new Codification(fulldata);
int[][] testinput = codebook.Apply(testData, inputColumnNameArray);
```

The confusion for me lay in all the example code seemingly randomly using these two methods, but using the Apply method only when processing the training data, and using the Transform method when encoding test data.

I am not sure why they chose to do this in the documentation example code, but it definitely took me a long time to figure out what was going on enough to stop having this particular issue.